# Write a NSMutableArray in a text file

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

i'm trying to write a table in a txt file, but my code seems doesn't working.

```
    Action *action1 = [[Action alloc] init];
    Action *action2 = [[Action alloc] init];
    ActionEtrangere *action3 = [[ActionEtrangere alloc] init];

    [action1 setPrixAchatAction:2.30];
    [action1 setPrixActuelAction:4.50];
    [action1 setNbActions:40];

    [action2 setPrixAchatAction:12.19];
    [action2 setPrixActuelAction:10.59];
    [action2 setNbActions:90];

    [action3 setPrixAchatAction:45.10];
    [action3 setPrixActuelAction:49.51];
    [action3 setNbActions:210];
    [action3 setTauxConversion:0.94];

    NSMutableArray *porteMonnaie = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:action1, action2, action3, nil];

    for (Action *p in porteMonnaie) {
        NSLog(@"Le cout en euros est de %.2f et la valeur en euro de %.2f", [p coutEnEuros], [p valeurEnEuros]);
    }

    //save des valeurs
    BOOL save = [porteMonnaie writeToFile:@"/tmp/save.txt" atomically:YES];

    if (!save) {
        NSLog(@"Error Save");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Save ok");
    }

}
return 0;
```

}

if you have some idea ! maybe i can't write a mutable in a txt ?

thanks

Comment: what kind of path is this: `@"/tmp/save.txt"`? where did you get that path from?

Comment: What return value comes from the writeToFile operation?

Comment: i have the "error save" message

Comment: Is the Action class serializable?

Comment: @vikingosegundo no and i think it is the problem

Comment: I reconstructed your action classes as I understand your code. But as you are dealing with currencies you might want to have a look into NSDecimal, NSDecimalNumber & NSNumberFormatter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`writeToFile:automatically:` isn't able to write custom objects to disk.

You can do so by implementing the NSCoding protocol and use NSKeyedArchiver to write to and NSKeyedUnarchiver to read from disk.

the protocol has two methods you must implement.

`-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder` and `-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder`.

For Action it might be

```
@implementation Action

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    self.prixAchatAction = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"prixAchatAction"] doubleValue];
    self.prixActuelAction = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"prixActuelAction"] doubleValue];
    self.nbActions = [decoder decodeIntegerForKey:@"nbActions"];

    return self;
}

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    [encoder encodeObject:@(self.prixAchatAction) forKey:@"prixAchatAction"];
    [encoder encodeObject:@(self.prixActuelAction) forKey:@"prixActuelAction"];
    [encoder encodeInteger:self.nbActions forKey:@"nbActions"];

}

@end
```

And for ActionEtrangere

```
@interface ActionEtrangere : Action
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat tauxConversion;
@end

@implementation ActionEtrangere
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:decoder];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }
    self.tauxConversion = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"tauxConversion"] doubleValue];

    return self;
}

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    [super encodeWithCoder:encoder];
    [encoder encodeObject:@(self.tauxConversion) forKey:@"tauxConversion"];
}
```

Now you can write your portemonnaie like:

```
BOOL success = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:porteMonnaie
                                           toFile:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"portemonnaie"]];
if(!success) {
    NSLog(@"something went wrong");
}
```

And read it like:

```
NSArray *newporteMonnaie = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"portemonnaie"]];
```

---

A full command line program:

---

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface Action : NSObject <NSCoding>
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat prixAchatAction;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat prixActuelAction;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger nbActions;

@end

@implementation Action

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    self.prixAchatAction = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"prixAchatAction"] doubleValue];
    self.prixActuelAction = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"prixActuelAction"] doubleValue];
    self.nbActions = [decoder decodeIntegerForKey:@"nbActions"];

    return self;
}

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    [encoder encodeObject:@(self.prixAchatAction) forKey:@"prixAchatAction"];
    [encoder encodeObject:@(self.prixActuelAction) forKey:@"prixActuelAction"];
    [encoder encodeInteger:self.nbActions forKey:@"nbActions"];

}

@end


@interface ActionEtrangere : Action
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat tauxConversion;
@end

@implementation ActionEtrangere
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:decoder];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }
    self.tauxConversion = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"tauxConversion"] doubleValue];

    return self;
}

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    [super encodeWithCoder:encoder];
    [encoder encodeObject:@(self.tauxConversion) forKey:@"tauxConversion"];
}


@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        Action *action1 = [[Action alloc] init];
        Action *action2 = [[Action alloc] init];
        ActionEtrangere *action3 = [[ActionEtrangere alloc] init];

        [action1 setPrixAchatAction:2.30];
        [action1 setPrixActuelAction:4.50];
        [action1 setNbActions:40];

        [action2 setPrixAchatAction:12.19];
        [action2 setPrixActuelAction:10.59];
        [action2 setNbActions:90];

        [action3 setPrixAchatAction:45.10];
        [action3 setPrixActuelAction:49.51];
        [action3 setNbActions:210];
        [action3 setTauxConversion:0.94];

        NSArray *porteMonnaie = @[action1, action2,action3];

        BOOL success = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:porteMonnaie
                                                   toFile:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"portemonnaie2.plist"]];
        if(!success) {
            NSLog(@"something went wrong");
        } else {
            NSArray *newporteMonnaie = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"portemonnaie2.plist"]];

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: de rien! If you have questions regarding the code, just ask.

Answer (score 1):

you may want to save your file into your application's *sandbox* instead, I guess:

```
NSString *_filename = @"save.txt"
NSURL *_resourceURL = [[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject] URLByAppendingPathComponent:_fileName];
```

I also assume that all items in the array conforms the `NSCoding` protocol, so that should work now:

```
NSMutableArray *porteMonnaie = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:action1, action2, action3, nil];
BOOL _isSaved = [porteMonnaie writeToFile:[_resourceURL path] atomically:TRUE];
```

Comment: @kambala, I did not want to confuse the OP with changing everything. :)

Comment: the sooner one starts writing more correctly the better :)

Comment: dear Downvoter! that you for the nice explanation which can highlight how poor my answer is, and helps me to improve it! thank you again so much! (sarcasm, idiot).

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why your array is not writing to file:-

As per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html), `writeToFile:automatically:` only works if your array's contents are following of types `(NSString, NSData, NSArray, or NSDictionary objects)`. If you have any other type of object in your array, then it will not write to file correctly. And that `bool` flag will always return **NO**

Comment: This is an iOS question. A path like `/User/home/...` is not valid either.

Comment: path is good, i just test to write a file in path with a string and working, i think i can't write a NSMutableArray in a txt file